# Simply importing react-native-draggable-flatlist into my Expo app breaks it

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I am trying to build a reordable list in React Native using `react-native-draggable-flatlist`, when i import anything from that library i get

```
 ERROR Error: Exception in HostFunction: expected 0 arguments, got 1, js engine: hermes
 at ContextNavigator ...

 WARN [Layout children]: No route named "garage" exists in nested children: ["contatti", "cronologia", "debugmenu", "index", "tappe", "_sitemap", "+not-found"]
```

I do have a `garage.js` file in my app and it runs just fine, but just importing the library breaks the app, this is the import:

```js
import DraggableFlatList from "react-native-draggable-flatlist";
```

**Note: i am using Expo Tab routing**

I tried reinstalling the library but nothing worked, even the [example in the official npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-flatlist#example) does not work (at least for me), is the library broken? I cannot find any similar issue online. Any help is greatly appreciated